# Air resistance due to Helium vs Air

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, rotation, power

I was reading this [technical note by NASA](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19680027690/downloads/19680027690.pdf) on windage power loss in alternators. In the paper, the power loss due to fluid shear between two concentric cylinders (a rotor and a stator) is derived.

The power loss is:
$$
W=\frac{2\pi\mu R^3\omega^2 L}{t}
$$
where:
$\mu$ is the dynamic viscosity
R is the radius of the rotor
$\omega$ is the angular velocity of the rotor
L is the cylinder length and t is the air gap distance between the rotor and stator.

Using this equation, it appears that all else equal, an air gap filled with Helium should result in higher energy loss than air since Helium has a higher dynamic viscosity than air. This "shortcoming" of Helium surprised me since I've seen that Helium can be used in [hard drives](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225162945_Thermal_analysis_of_helium-filled_enterprise_disk_drive) to reduce windage power losses.

Am I misinterpreting this equation or is air really better than Helium despite air's higher density?